# Create column from other columns in Database

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table name: *test*
*ID | Prefix | ACCID*
**ID**'s type is INTEGER which is selected from *ID_SEQ*
**Prefix**'s type is VARCHAR(6)
**ACCID** is the combination of Prefix + ID

I want to auto-create ACCID when I insert the ID and Prefix value such as

```
INSERT INTO TEST (PREFIX) VALUES ('A01407V');
```

and the database store the ACCID as *'A01407V000001'*

I create the sequence as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ AS INT MAXVALUE 999999 CYCLE;
```

How to implement SQL statement to produce this result?
Thank you for all solutions and suggestions.

Ps. I use *Apache Derby* as my SQL Server

Comment: Why would you want to *store* that value? In general storing data that can be calculated by the existing data doesn't make much sense. You can create a view that hides this "formula".

Comment: Which value that you mean? the Sequence? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: No, I mean the `ACCID` column. You can always generate the desired value by selecting `prefix||id`. Btw: Derby supportes generated columns. See the manual for details: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqljgenerationclause.html#rrefsqljgenerationclause

Answer (score 2):

As [documented in the manual](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefsqljgenerationclause.html#rrefsqljgenerationclause), Derby supports generated columns (since Version 10.5)

The real problem is the formatting of a number with leading zeros as Derby has no function for that.

If you really, really think you need to store a value that can always be determined by the values already stored in the table, you can use something like this:

```
create table test
(
  id integer,
  prefix varchar(6),
  accid  generated always as (prefix||substr('000000', 1, 6 - length(rtrim(char(id))))||rtrim(char(id)))
);
```

The expression `substr('000000', 1, 6 - length(rtrim(char(id))))||rtrim(char(id))` is just a complicated way to format a the ID with leading zeros.

I would highly recommend to not store this value though. It is much cleaner to create a view that shows this value if you do need access to this in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use COMPUTED Column.

Is a computed column that is based on some other column in the table. We can physically save the data of the column/ or not. Table will automatically update the value of this column.

```
syntax:
    columnname AS expression [PERSISTED]  

--PERSISTED will make it physically saved, otherwise it will be calculated every time.
```

We can create indexes on computed columns.

You add, The following in the table CREATE Script

```
ACCID AS Prefix + CAST(ID AS CHAR(6)) [PERSISTED]
```

Comment: Is COMPUTED Column allowed in MySQL? I try this in SQL Fiddle but it show the error

_Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (PREFIX + '000') PERSISTED,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)_

@Jithin Shaji

Comment: @PandarianLd: why are you asking about MySQL when your question is tagged with `Derby`? Those are two different things.

Comment: It my misunderstanding that all SQL statements in MySQL can be used in Apache Derby. @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for told me that.